# how do i search on specific text then from start of the searched line to end of line to replace with ""

Tags: notepad++

```
SkinMesh
{
    skin = "Art/Models/Effects/monster_effects/League_Affliction/affliction_demon_lightning/lightning_warp/geo.sm"
}

ParticleEffects
{
    animation = "start"
        0 = "midline Metadata/Particles/monster_effects/League_Affliction/affliction_demon_lightning/lightning_warp/marker_start.pet"
    animation = "loop"
        0 = "midline Metadata/Particles/monster_effects/League_Affliction/affliction_demon_lightning/lightning_warp/marker_loop.pet"
    tick_when_not_visible = true
}
```

What i want to from search/replace is this

```
SkinMesh
{
}

ParticlesEffects
{
}
```

Comment: Also, I want to search it for all opened document

Comment: Have you tried something? What didn't work?

Comment: Tried searching on the internet but can't find one :(

Comment: (?<=\{).+?(?=\})

Found this somewhere in stackoverflow but all it does is it search inside the { } brackets
I want to include the "SkinMesh" then get the strings inside the bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:SkinMesh|ParticleEffects)\s+{\K.+?(?=\R})`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    SkinMesh            # literally
  |                   # OR
    ParticleEffects     # literally
)                   # end group
\s+                 # 1 or more spaces
{                   # opening brace
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?                 # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=\R})             # positive lookahead, make sure we have a linebreak and a closing brace after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]